# Download Progress in Android

Tags: android

i have developed an app which shows progress of downloads in a progress bar.

```
while ((chunkBytes = httpInputStream.read(outputByte, 0, 1024)) != -1) {

                bytesRead = bytesRead + chunkBytes;
                // write contents to the file
                fileOutputStream.write(outputByte, 0, (int) chunkBytes);
                // publish the progress of downloading.. 
                publishProgress((int)((bytesRead)*100/fileSize));

            }
```

But, what i am trying to do is - instead of that 58/100 .. (secondary progress ?) would like to display 3.5 mb/5.5 mb .... (MBs downloaded / Total MB) below that progress.. i have tried to change the secondary progress but of no help..  Is there any other way?

Comment: The `bytesRead` and `fileSize` variables contain the no. of bytes read and total no. of bytes to be read, right? So just divide them each by 1048576 to convert those numbers to megabytes! Its just units!

Comment: The problem will be with showing those "mb". I don't think that there is an easy way to do it. Maybe through reflection? Or maybe it will be simpler to implement your own ProgressDialog.

Comment: No no, i am not worried about converting those MBs to Bytes..(not about the unit) those things are working fine.. When you download apps from Google Play Store -- the secondary progress shows it.. (Primary progress shows -- percentage.. just below it shows it which is what i am looking for..

Comment: It is like how to show the remaining KB's of file is to be downloaded in progress bar in android. e.g 12kb/120kb is remaining..then 97kb/120kb...etc

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change what's displayed in your progress bar, you have to call `setProgressNumberFormat()` with a string parameter, which says what you would like to see, for example, "%1d/%2d" will show the default "20/100" message, while "%1d MB of %2d MB" will show something you are asking about. "%1d" is your current progress value, and "%2d" is your maximum value, which your may change with `setMax(int max)`.